# How to access instance variable defined within class << self

Tags: ruby

Given the following code, how come `Dog.speak` does not return `"here is the @var variable"`:

```
class Dog
  class << self
    @var = "here is the @var variable"

    def speak
      @var
    end
  end
end

p Dog.speak
```

Instead it returns `nil`

My understanding: `class << self` opens up the singleton class object of `Dog`.  On that singleton object, we are setting the instance variable of `@var`.  Thus, I would think that the instance variable of `@var` is accessible from `Dog.speak`.

What concepts am I missing here?  Why is `@var` not accessible to the `speak` method?

Confusingly, this however works as expected:

```
class Dog
  class << self
    def set_it
      @var = "The instance variable of @var is now accessible"
    end

    def speak
      @var
    end
  end
end

Dog.set_it
p Dog.speak # => "The instance variable of @var is now accessible"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare the variable on singleton class level and try to access it on class level. Debug output is your friend:

```
class Dog
  class << self
    puts "I am #{self}"
    @var = "here is the @var variable"

    def speak
      puts "I am #{self}"
      @var
    end
  end
end
```

Prints out:

```
#⇒ I am #<Class:Dog>
▶ Dog.speak
#⇒ I am Dog
```

Note, that the former is printed *while the code is parsed* and the latter is printed only when the call to `Dog.speak` is explicitly performed.

Comment: could you possibly explain how `#<Class:Dog>` and `Dog` are different things? I think I am getting confused because I thought they both referred to the same object.  That is: that they both refer to the Singleton class object of: `Dog`.

Comment: `Dog` refers to the _instance_ of `Dog`’s singleton class (namely, to `Dog` class itself.) `#<Class:Dog>` refers to the `Dog`’s singleton class.

Comment: @Neil: "that they both refer to the Singleton class object of: Dog" - how can a thing also be a singleton class object of itself? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: ah-ha, that was what I was missing.  Thanks you guys!

Comment: "the former is printed while the code is parsed" I don't think this is correct. AFAIK class bodies are executed just like any other Ruby expression, there's isn't a special "eval classes" phase before other code is run.

Comment: @Max well, “while the code is being loaded for the first time and executed on class level.” I meant, `require "this_file"` would make this `puts` to get executed. No call is needed, unlike with `Dog.speak`.

Answer (score 2):

> how come `Dog.speak` does not return `"here is the @var variable"`

For the very same reason why this behaves similarly:

```
class Dog
  @var = "here is the @var variable"

  def speak
    @var
  end
end

Dog.new.speak # => nil
```

You set variable on class level and expect it to be available on instance level.